# Взаимодействие контроллов в строке редактирования GridView

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

Доброго времени суток, господа.
Как заставить взаимодействовать два листбокса в строке редактирования ?

```
<EditItemTemplate>
       <asp:ListBox ID="ListBox6" runat="server" Rows="5" Width="132px"></asp:ListBox>
       <asp:ListBox ID="ListBox5" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource2" DataTextField="breakname" DataValueField="breakdownID" Rows="5" SelectionMode="Multiple" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ListBox5_SelectedIndexChanged"></asp:ListBox>
</EditItemTemplate>
```

Нужно, чтобы всё выбранное в 5ом, кидалось в 6ой, но данный метод

```
protected void ListBox5_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ((ListBox)GridView1.FindControl("ListBox6")).Items.Clear();

        foreach (ListItem li in ((ListBox)GridView1.FindControl("ListBox6")).Items)
        {
            if (li.Selected)
            {
                ((ListBox)GridView1.FindControl("ListBox5")).Items.Add(li.Text);
            }
        }
    }
```

Даёт *NullReferenceException*. Как я понимаю, нужно как-то передавать индекс строки, которую редактируют, чтобы контролл находился

Answer (score 1):

Спасибо всем прочитавшим, поспешил писать сюда. Решение вот такое если кому интересно

```
protected void ListBox5_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        GridViewRow row = GridView1.Rows[GridView1.EditIndex];
        ((ListBox)row.FindControl("ListBox6")).Items.Clear();

        foreach (ListItem li in ((ListBox)row.FindControl("ListBox5")).Items)
        {
            if (li.Selected)
            {
                ((ListBox)row.FindControl("ListBox6")).Items.Add(li.Text);
            }
        }
    }
```